# Чи можна утворювати прислівники від "місткий" і "ємкий" і сполучати ці прислівники з дієслівними формами

Tags: прислівники

Надибав [статтю](http://www.philology.kiev.ua/Lingur/art_94.htm) на сайті лінгвістичного гуртка витяг з якої наводжу тут:

> Тому не можна виправдати стилістичне розширення слововжитку ємкість і
>   ємкісний (трапляється навіть ємко) у переносному значенні. Стилістично
>   невдалі, штучні фрази, де прислівники містко, ємко, утворені від
>   відповідних прикметників, сполучаються з дієслівними формами, напр.:
>   “*В оповіданні “Доля людини”, що увібрало в себе матеріал роману,
>   надзвичайно містко показано зв'язок людської долі з долею народною*”
>   (“Радянське літературознавство”); “*Ніхто не розповідав про нього
>   [Нюрнберзький процес] так ємко, з таким знанням справи, з такою
>   ерудицією, як Ярослав Галан*” (“Мистецтво”).
>
> Містко показати, ємко розповісти — штучні вислови, в яких втрачається
>   значення прислівників-означень. Крім того, в переносному значенні, як
>   і в прямому доцільно вживати тільки нормативний для сучасно
>   української мови прикметник місткий і похідні від нього слова.

Але так і не зрозумів чому ж не можна *містко показати* чи *ємко розповісти*?